# Enumeration Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A board game contains three bags: a blue one, a red one, and a green one. The game also
contains 5 gaming chips labeled with the numbers 1 to 5.
(a) Explain why there are 243 ways of distributing all the chips over the bags. (There is no order of chips within a bag. It only matters which chip is in which bag.)

(b) In how many ways can all the chips be distributed over the bags so that the red bag
is not empty?

(c) In how many ways can some or all chips be put into the bags? (I.e. not every chip
needs to go into a bag.)

(d) In how many ways can you put exactly 3 chips into the green bag and 2 chips into
the blue bag?

(e) Now the chips are removed from the bags (and you can forget about the bags). Two
stacks are formed from the chips, one for Player A and one for Player B. Note that
stacks do have an order, i.e. it matters which chips are on top of which other chips.
i. In how many ways can the chips be stacked if all the chips are in Player A’s
stack?

I really don't understand how to do the first part if someone can explain then I can do the second part

Comment: Hint:  How many ways can you place each chip in a bag?

Comment: so that can vary you could have 1 in the red bag 2 in the green bag and 1 in the blue bag for example? @N.F.Taussig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) For each chip, the chip may either be put in the blue bag or red bag, or green bag. So, there are three possibilities for each chip. Thus, by the fundamental principle of multiplication, there are a total of $3\times3\times3\times 3\times 3=3^5=243$ possibilities.

(b) The number of ways in which all the chips go to the other two bags
is $2^5=32$. Consequently, the required number is $3^5-2^5=243-32=211$.

(c) In this case, the required number is $4^5-1=1024-1=1023$ ways.

(d) For this, you choose the three you want to put into the green one. The required number would be $C(5,3)=10$.

(e) It would be $5!=120$.

Comment: Hi Firdous Mala thank you very much for answering that question! would you be able to help me with b)?

Comment: I have got an answer of 239/243 because I did 1-4/243 is that correct?

Comment: @Maths99 Not at all.  (b) is a counting problem and so has a counting answer... i.e. a non-negative integer.  Your attempt at (b) you had a fraction... It looks like you tried to find a probability when the problem did not ask for it.  Do not confuse probability questions with counting questions, they are not the same.  As for your attempted probability... it makes no sense where you got the $4$ from in $4/243$.

Comment: For c) I think the answer should be $4^5$, since for every chip, you now have $4$ possibilities for where it goes (one of the three bags, or not in any bag).

Comment: That would be wrong, as that includes the possibility that all the bags are empty.

Comment: @Anand is correct.  The value Firdous calculated for (c) is incorrect and is instead the number of ways of having either chips $1$, or chips $1$ and $2$, or chips $1$ and $2$ and $3$, etc... used and put into bags, where we always used at least one chip and used only the smallest numbered chips and missed cases such as where we only used chips $2$ and $5$ or where we used no chips at all.  If avoiding the case of not having used any chips at all then it would be $4^5-1$

Comment: Which answer is correct?

Comment: I have edited the answers. Have another look.

Comment: Also part d for par d? @FirdousMala

Comment: Thank you for answering the other parts really appreciate it! @FirdousMala

Comment: so would it be 5C3 * 2C2 ? @FirdousMala

Comment: Yes. $5C3\times 2C2=10$.

Answer (score 0):

(a) $243$  (b) $211$ (c) $1023$ (d) $10$ (e) $120$